# Can I return std::result::Result from a Future?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand Rust futures. I did:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ClientError {
    UrlParseError((String, String)),
    BindError
}

pub async fn connect(addr: std::net::SocketAddr) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ClientError>> {
    let listener = async_std::net::TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = match listener {
        Ok(listener) => listener,
        Err(_) => return Err(ClientError::BindError)
    };
    //Ok(())
    std::future::ready(Ok(()))
}
```

I get

```
error[E0277]: `std::result::Result<_, ClientError>` is not a future
 --> src/lib.rs:7:53
  |
7 | pub async fn connect(addr: std::net::SocketAddr) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ClientError>> {
  |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::result::Result<_, ClientError>` is not a future
  |
  = help: the trait `Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<_, ClientError>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     std::future::ready(Ok(()))
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found struct `std::future::Ready`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, ClientError>`
            found struct `std::future::Ready<std::result::Result<(), _>>`
note: return type inferred to be `std::result::Result<_, ClientError>` here
  --> src/lib.rs:11:26
   |
11 |         Err(_) => return Err(ClientError::BindError)
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I honestly don't know what is wrong. I cannot return a `Result` from a future?

How can I fix this?

I tried returning just `Ok(())` and I don't get the second error

Comment: You don't need the impl Future in the return. That's implict in the async specifier.

Comment: @user1937198 then I get an error about size not being known at compile time

Comment: inside this connect function? That doesn't sound right. Can you post a [mcve] so we can more clearly see what is missing.

Comment: @user1937198 I tried, this is a minimal reproducible example except that async_std needs to be imported. I tried putting in the playground but it does not have async_stc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this works for you?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ClientError {
    UrlParseError((String, String)),
    BindError
}

pub async fn connect(addr: std::net::SocketAddr) -> Result<(), ClientError> {
    let listener = async_std::net::TcpListener::bind(&addr)
        .await
        .or(Err(ClientError::BindError))?
    ;

    Ok(())
}
```